# How to handle multiple forms on same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following HTML:

```
<form method='post' name='form".$post->ID."' >
   <input type='submit' name='bid".$post->ID."' value='Licitar' class='bidvalue'>
</form>
```

And I have the following jQuery **inside a PHP loop** to handle the submit event:

```
<script>
jQuery('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: 'action=newbid&id=".$post->ID."',
        success: function(msg){
            jQuery('#vehicle-value-box".$post->ID."').html(msg+',00€');
        }
});
</script>
```

When the user clicks on the submit button, I want to update the value of the current bid and update the box with that value with AJAX. I'm doing it in functions.php with:

```
function newbid_ajax() {
    $post_id = $_POST['id'];
    $mybid = get_post_meta($post_id, 'start_price', true);
    $mybid = $mybid + 100;
    update_post_meta($post_id,'start_price',$mybid);
    die($mybid);
}
```

However, I can't handle the form submit events **separately**. I have 3 test auctions. When I click on Auction #1, it updates the value of Auction #2; when I click on Auction #2, it updates Auction #3; when I click Auction #3, nothing is updated and e.preventDefault(); doesn't work (the page is reloaded).

You can take a look at the website at this [location](http://standcardeira.com/leiloes/zona-exclusiva/). The submit button has the text "LICITAR".

I understand there are other posts out there regarding this problem, but somehow I can't manage to adapt their solutions to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see if changing input type to button rather than submit helps any way as you are submitting with ajax. also if there are multiple submit buttons on your form this will not work as each time it will fire the same ajax call on submit. while give seperate ids to your buttons and replace your jquery selectors

Comment: Is that jQuery <script>...</script> inside some PHP loop? If yes, You probably have 3 onclick events on all submit buttons, each onclick with different $post->ID. See the source code of the produced HTML page if this is the case. You'll then have to use jQuery('form[name=".$post->ID."] input[type=submit]')

Comment: @HarshadaChavan Changing it to button didn't help.

Comment: @RomanHocke Yes, it is inside a PHP loop. Adding form[name=".$post->ID."] to that script won't work, the page reloads and no value is updated.

Comment: Sorry, I mean form[name=form".$post->ID."] input[type=submit]

Comment: Tried that but I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of the provided URL you have a jQuery click handler for each form:

```
jQuery('input[type=submit]')
```

This approach could result in more than one binding for each form submit button, depending on how the code is structured.

The solution is to have only one click handler declared inside a `$( document ).ready(...)`.
The button and function below have been modified to work on this scenario (not tested):

```
<input type='submit' name='".$post->ID."' value='Licitar' class='bidvalue'>
```

The function below declared only once, outside any loop, and generally in the `<head></head>` section of the document.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('.bidvalue').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: 'action=newbid&id='+e.target.name,
            success: function(msg){
                jQuery('#vehicle-value-box'+e.target.name).html(msg+',00€');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's an improvement. But I still have two issues. One, I have other different submits on my website, namely the login submit. How can I edit that script to work only with the auctions submits? And two, somehow the box with the value isn't updating properly, instead of having the new value it changes to ",00€". The msg variable seems to be empty.

Comment: You can select the button by class, instead of selecting every submit button: `jQuery('.bidvalue')`. I've also updated the script above.

Comment: You can also debug the `msg` variable value by `console.debug()` or `alert`ing it, so you know if the problem comes from the server.

Comment: That was obvious, my bad! Thanks. Any thoughts on the value box update?

Comment: That's ok! Have you tested if the server is returning the correct value?

Comment: The server is returning null. Shouldn't die($mybid) return the value of that variable and assign it to msg on success: function(msg)?

Comment: Could you share the source of the php script in a pastebin so we can take a look?

Comment: Isn't that the newbid_ajax function I posted above?

Comment: You shouldn't try to output a number using `die()` as that would be equivalent to `exit()`, the number acts as an exit status and will not be printed. To make sure the number gets returned by your script you should explicitly `echo` it: `echo $mybid;`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Answer (score 0):

if i udnerstand your correctly you have mulitple forms and eatch for needs to have his own ajax function?

Than you have to give the submit a id:

```
<form method='post' name='form".$post->ID."' >
   <input type='submit' name='bid".$post->ID."' id="submit-1" value='Licitar' class='bidvalue'>
</form>
```

New js:

```
<script>
$('form').submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: 'action=newbid&id=".$post->ID."',
        success: function(msg){
            jQuery('#vehicle-value-box".$post->ID."').html(msg+',00€');
        }
});
</script>
```

Edited try that

Comment: I've tried adding to the input tag id='submit".$post->ID."' and then changing the script to jQuery('#submit".$post->ID."').click (...). I have the same problem with Roman Hocke's suggestion, doing this the page reloads and no value is updated.

Comment: That edit puts it back into the original problem: the values are updated but not in the right auction. I might add all of that is inside a loop.